# Header won't attach the font

Tags: css

I have problem attaching the font to my header at http://12hrs.net/guides/12-hrs-in-antwerp/

All the other css parameters (inside h2) are working just fine, but for some reason the font ("proxima-nova") won't change.

Is there maybe another fond over-ruling somewhere else?

Best,
S

Comment: Are you sure to have loaded the `proxima-nova` font via @font-face or data:URI? Because I'm not able to see it loaded by the server.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried putting !important within the styling declaration?

```
h2 {
    font-family: arial !important;
}
```

i just tried this with google dev and it worked

```
.blog .titleBar h2 {
    font-family: arial !important;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I sadly did! No luck so far.

Comment: I think I found the reason. The webkit script didn't load on that page, so I attached it there too, and it finally seems to work. I added !important like you said as well, just in case. THANK YOU

Comment: I think you mean Typekit script, not Webkit :)

Answer (score 1):

Inspecting the CSS rules in effect for the H2, it seems that your font would have been used had it been present. As Ragnarrokkr mentions, the font doesn't seem to get loaded by the browser so most likely you don't have an @font-face rule defining this font anywhere.

Also, you have lots of contents before your doctype declaration. You should fix this too as it can probably cause all sorts of problems.

Comment: see answer above :) Regarding the content before my doctype declaration, I honestly have no idea what you mean :) In my header.php?

Comment: I have no idea what's in your php files, can only see the resulting HTML at the URL you included. The doctype is supposed to be the very first thing on an HTML page. In your case it looks like this: `<!DOCTYPE html>`.